# countif as long as they are numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

how can I set up a formula, that counts all values that are `<>0`and also `=0`.
The obvious formula is:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:E8,"<>0")
```

How can I integrate all value with ZERO as well.

merci

A

Comment: Since the union of all values that are not zero and all values that are zero is **all** values. Why not use a `COUNTA`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `COUNTIF()` is not needed. To count all numbers *(zero, positive, negative)*:

```
=COUNT(A1:E8)
```

This will not count blanks or text.

[image]